# No such module 'ARKit'. Import error in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, arkit

I am a beginner in iOS development.

I started a new project > app > SwiftUI > Swift

I need to import ARKit for my project but I am receiving an error stating "No such module 'ARKit'." How do I fix this?

Does this require cocoapods?

Any link to documentation or a clear description of how to fix this error would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Did you create a new iOS project or a Multiplatform project? ARKit is not available on macOS so if you chose Multiplatform that won't compile.

Comment: I just checked in xCode 14, created an iOS project as you described, ARKit imports well both in the testApp.swift and ContentView.swift.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez you fixed my problem! I wasn't aware that I needed to hit iOS and not Multiplatform for ARKit to import. It makes so much sense. 

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARKit is not available on macOS so if you chose Multiplatform that won't compile.

Create a new iOS project so that ARKit can be imported